# Xml iteration not iterating through tags for Open source Map

Tags: pandas, xml

I'm really new to XML and I'm working to try and get a dictionary of code into a  Pandas DF to analyze it. I exported a map portion from Open Street Maps, and used the following code to change it to a Pandas DF.

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def xml_to_dic(xml_doc):
    attrib= xml_doc.attrib
    for xml in xml_doc.iter('node'):
        dict = attrib.copy()
        dict.update(xml.attrib)
        
        yield dict

etree = et.parse('mapreno.osm')
eroot = etree.getroot()
change = xml_to_dic(eroot)


df = pd.DataFrame(list(change))
```

My Opeen Street Map XML code is built like this:

```
<OSM>
<Node>
<Tag K= ""  v = ""/>
</Node>
</OSM>
```

However if I use `xml_doc.iter('osm'):`, none of the nodes are included, and when I use `xml_doc.iter('node'):`, it will not include any of the tag information in the DF Indexes. Is there any way for me to iterate all the information? including the tags? So that I can query the tag k or tag v information?

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive: it's `Node` and `OSM`.